# There are content that is good. Would this be a correct sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

> There are content that is good.

It uses "are" and "is" in the same sentence. Is that correct?

Comment: No it is incorrect. Why did you write, "There are content"?  What makes you think that is correct?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK content refers to many individual pieces of content so I thought it was potentially plural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content is a singular noun and always takes a singular verb.

Confusingly, "contents" has a very similar meaning and is a plural noun that always takes a plural verb.

It's worth noting that American English uses singular verbs for collective/group nouns, while British English uses plural verbs for the same nouns.  For example: "The group of people is doing well." / "The group of people are doing well."

Regardless, in this context, stick with the singular verb, and maintain consistency. "There is content that is good." Or: "There are contents that are good."